# How to move content resource when it is set to Copy if newer?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, resources, buildaction

I have few resources that i have put into `Dependencies` Folder in the Project. 
**Copy To Output Directory** is set to **Copy If Newer**

Default Behavior is that it will copy to `\bin\Dependencies\*`

I want to set it to copy to `\bin\*`

How to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you need them to be in the bin folder, you need to put the files in the root of the project.

The only other way i can think of doing it is to add a post-build event to the project which copies them each time:

```
copy "$(ProjectDir)Dependencies\*" "$(TargetDir)"
```